# Nested Resources With Form For Gives: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-resources, nested-routes

I'm trying to create an edit page for a nested route.

The url is something like: `http://localhost:3000/clients/2/notes/3/edit`

my routes.rb:

```
 resources :clients do
    resources :notes
  end
```

In my edit controller:

```
def edit
  @note = Note.find(params[:id])
  @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
end
```

and my edit.html.erb file

```
<%= form_for(@client, @note) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.text_field :content %> 
    <%= f.submit "Save changes" %>
<% end %>
```

When I do this and load the edit page, I get the following:
[image]

I've looked around on stack overflow and they all have two arguments when using nested routes, what is the correct thing to do here? And why is it different?

Update:

```
rake routes
           users GET    /users(.:format)                             users#index
                 POST   /users(.:format)                             users#create
        new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                         users#new
       edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                    users#edit
            user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                         users#show
                 PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                         users#update
                 DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                         users#destroy
        sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)                          sessions#create
     new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                      sessions#new
         session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)                      sessions#destroy
    client_notes GET    /clients/:client_id/notes(.:format)          notes#index
                 POST   /clients/:client_id/notes(.:format)          notes#create
 new_client_note GET    /clients/:client_id/notes/new(.:format)      notes#new
edit_client_note GET    /clients/:client_id/notes/:id/edit(.:format) notes#edit
     client_note GET    /clients/:client_id/notes/:id(.:format)      notes#show
                 PUT    /clients/:client_id/notes/:id(.:format)      notes#update
                 DELETE /clients/:client_id/notes/:id(.:format)      notes#destroy
         clients GET    /clients(.:format)                           clients#index
                 POST   /clients(.:format)                           clients#create
      new_client GET    /clients/new(.:format)                       clients#new
     edit_client GET    /clients/:id/edit(.:format)                  clients#edit
          client GET    /clients/:id(.:format)                       clients#show
                 PUT    /clients/:id(.:format)                       clients#update
                 DELETE /clients/:id(.:format)                       clients#destroy
            root        /                                            clients#index
          signup        /signup(.:format)                            users#new
          signin        /signin(.:format)                            sessions#new
         signout DELETE /signout(.:format)                           sessions#destroy
```

Comment: whats the result of `rake routes`?

Comment: Try using brackets.. <%= form_for([@client, @note]) do |f| %>

Comment: @Çağdaş I've added rake routes.

Comment: @MurifoX adding brackets gets me: `undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass` which I think is actually an improvement. It means it's not finding notes, I think.

Comment: @Rob, I haven't defined to_param, I don't think. Is that something I would do in the controller?

Comment: @MurifoX Sorry, that fixed it. I was editing a bit of other code and got that other error. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it as the correct one. Do the brackets pass it as a single unit?

Comment: Just posted it as an answer. I have struggled with this issue in the past. The brackets means it is an array. Rails interprets this values and builds a nested form with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using brackets..

```
<%= form_for([@client, @note]) do |f| %>
```